# How to define a unique validateForm for two forms on same page?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am wanting to know how to identify a unique form validation function. See example below:

```
 //  Form #1
 function validateForm(sideform) {
  // do this
  }

 //  Form #2
 function validateForm(bottomform) { 
 // do this
 }


  //HTML
  <!---FORM #1--------->
  <form action="sideform.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(sideform)" >
  </form>

  <!---FORM #2--------->
  <form action="bottomform.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(bottomform)" >
  </form>
```

This method I am using now, isn't working.

Comment: what is unique in this??

Comment: I have two forms on the same page and when I submit one, it is wanting to use the other function. I need these to call up their own function.

Comment: both the forms will have their unique elements.Assign thier respective elements their respective validation function.I dont undersand the uniqueness you are talking about?

Comment: I don't know how you assign their unique elements.

Comment: I figured it out - return validateForm2(), and return validateForm()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two separate functions for both the forms and call these functions on their respective submit buttons.

```
function validate_sideform() {
      // do this
      }

     //  Form #2
     function validate_bottomform() { 
     // do this
     }


      //HTML
      <!---FORM #1--------->
      <form action="sideform.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_sideform()" >
      </form>

      <!---FORM #2--------->
      <form action="bottomform.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_bottomform()" >
      </form>
```